# How to append items at input text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function to append items whenever I click one. How can I make them appear at input text field and have a Add button to store all of the items clicked ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btn<%= item.id %>").click(function(){
        var itemcontent = "<%= item.content %> : <%= item.price %>";
        $("ol").append("<li>" + itemcontent + "</li>");

    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see any text field.

Comment: you can append to a textarea

Answer (score 0):

[HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) is [empty element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element). So it can't content any other DOM elements. It shows only `value` attribute text, if it's `type` attribute is `text`, `search`, etc.

Comment: so is there any solution to add items to text field by clicking ?

Comment: No, if it is `HTMLInputElement`.